# how do i use promises inside life cycle components in react-native?

Tags: react-native

im trying to use promise to query sqlite database in react native but i seem not to be getting it. this is my componentDidMount code:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    (() => {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          "create table if not exists tbl_register (id integer primary key not null, name text, contact text);"
        );
      });
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("good");
    });
  }
```

and this is the error im getting:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).then is not a function
Preprofile.componentDidMount
C:/Users/Denoh/Car-market/app/screens/preprofile.js:22
  19 |         "create table if not exists tbl_register (id integer primary key not null, name text, contact text);"
  20 |       );
  21 |     });
> 22 |   }).then(() => {
     | ^  23 |     console.log("good");
  24 |   });
  25 | }
```

please help

Comment: You are using .then in the arrow function, which is not a promise. I think u wanted to use it in executeSql don't you?

Comment: yes, how do i do it please

Comment: Just move your .then to the right place

Answer (score 0):

Checking the code we notice that you used `.then()` as a method to an arrow function. However, I think you wanted to place it in a promise, which has this method innately.

I'm not sure if `tx.executeSql()` returns a promise, but at first glance to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html), this method receives functions like a then and a catch inside its arguments.

`tx.executeSql(sqlupdate,*[updateParams]*,successOn, errorOn)`

```
componentDidMount() {
    (() => {
      db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
          "create table if not exists tbl_register (id integer primary key not null, name text, contact text)"
        [] , () => console.log("Good"), () => console.log("Error"))
      })
   })
}
```

Comment: it seems something is wrong. it doesnt log anything